# How can I populate part of a JSON object without repetitive code?

Tags: json, swift, post

I am making use of the Microsoft Graph API, specifically the FindMeetingTimes API. Which can be seen here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0

I am using Swift to develop this. My JSON object works and the post is successful, but I am just wondering what would be the best / most efficient way to alter this code so that it cuts out the repetitive code - specifically the adding of locations in the JSON. The locations list could be very large, so I would like to iterate through an locations array and add these to the JSON object..

My method looks like this:

```
static func setupJsonObjectForFindMeetingTimeAllRooms(nameOfRoom: String, roomEmailAddress: String, dateStartString: String, dateEndString: String, durationOfMeeting: String) -> [String: Any] {
    let jsonObj : [String: Any] =
        [
            "attendees": [
                [
                    "type": "required",
                    "emailAddress": [
                        "name": nameOfRoom,
                        "address": roomEmailAddress
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "locationConstraint": [
                "isRequired": "true",
                "suggestLocation": "false",
                "locations": [
                    [
                        "displayName": "First Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                        "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@microsoft.com"
                    ],
                    [
                        "displayName": "Ground Floor Test Meeting Room 1",
                        "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@microsoft.com"
                    ]
                    //and the rest of the rooms below this.. how do i do this outside in a loop? to prevent repetitive code?
                ]
            ],
            "timeConstraint": [
                "activityDomain":"unrestricted",
                "timeslots": [
                    [
                        "start": [
                            "dateTime": dateStartString,
                            "timeZone": Resources.utcString
                        ],
                        "end": [
                            "dateTime": dateEndString,
                            "timeZone": Resources.utcString
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "meetingDuration": durationOfMeeting,
            "returnSuggestionReasons": "true",
            "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100",
            "isOrganizerOptional": "true"
    ]
    return jsonObj
}
```

What is the best way to go about doing this? Would I just remove the locations part of the JSON, and before returning, populate it with the array of locations?

I tried to implement a method to add locations to the JSON - using this method:

```
static func addLocationsToExistingJson(locations: [String], jsonObj: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
        var  data: [String: Any] = jsonObj
        for i in stride(from: 0, to: locations.count, by: 1){
            let item: [String: Any] =  [
                "displayName": locations[i],
                "locationEmailAddress": locations[i]
            ]
            // get existing items, or create new array if doesn't exist
            var existingItems = data["locations"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()
            // append the item
            existingItems.append(item)
            // replace back into `data`
            data["locations"] = existingItems
        }
        return data
    }
```

and calling this method before returning the JSON in the original method.. But it seems that the final JSON is not the format that I want.
The incorrect version looks like this:

```
["timeConstraint": ["activityDomain": "unrestricted", "timeslots": [["start": ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 14:00:00", "timeZone": "UTC"], "end": ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 15:00:00", "timeZone": "UTC"]]]], "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100", "isOrganizerOptional": "true", "returnSuggestionReasons": "true", "meetingDuration": "PT60M", "attendees": [["type": "required", "emailAddress": ["name": "N", "address": "TestUser6@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"]]], "locationConstraint": ["isRequired": "true", "suggestLocation": "false"]]
```

Whereas the working JSON looks like this:

```
["timeConstraint": ["activityDomain": "unrestricted", "timeslots": [["start": ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 14:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"], "end": ["dateTime": "2019-02-07 15:30:00", "timeZone": "UTC"]]]], "attendees": [["type": "required", "emailAddress": ["name": "N", "address": "TestUser6@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"]]], "minimumAttendeePercentage": "100", "locations": [["displayName": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "locationEmailAddress": "FirstFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"], ["displayName": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com", "locationEmailAddress": "GroundFloorTestMeetingRoom1@qubbook.onmicrosoft.com"]], "locationConstraint": ["isRequired": "true", "suggestLocation": "false"], "meetingDuration": "PT60M", "isOrganizerOptional": "true", "returnSuggestionReasons": "true"]
```

How would I change my code so that the locations get added under the locationConstraint object within the JSON, rather than just to the JSON, not under the ["locationConstraint"] part?

Comment: Create a hierarchy of structs that correspond to your json structure

Comment: try swift Codable [learn here](https://medium.com/@multidots/essentials-of-codable-protocol-in-swift-4-c795a645c3e1)

Answer (score 0):

As [Joakim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) suggested, you could model the json structure via structs and Codable. For example:

```
    struct AdditionalData: Codable {
        let emailAdress: [String]
    }

    struct Person: Codable {
        let age: Int
        let name: String
        let additionalData: AdditionalData
    }

    let additionalData = AdditionalData(emailAdress: ["test@me.com", "foo@bar.com"])
    let p1 = Person(age: 30,
                    name: "Frank",
                    additionalData: additionalData)

    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    if let data = try? encoder.encode(p1),
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(jsonString)
    }
```

Which results in:

```
{
  "age" : 30,
  "name" : "Frank",
  "additionalData" : {
    "emailAdress" : [
      "test@me.com",
      "foo@bar.com"
    ]
  }
}
```